# Conflict between polyglossia and datetime package

Tags: polyglossia, datetime

The goal of my document is to have a date in the following format `<AAAA> <month> le <JJ>`, so I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[latin,russian,greek,french,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

\newdateformat{fauvedate}{\THEYEAR{} \shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]{} le {\THEDAY}}

\begin{document}

  \fauvedate\today

\end{document}
```

And I correctly get:

[image: 2015 novembre le 17]

But, when I add polyglossia like in the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[latin,russian,greek,french,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\newdateformat{fauvedate}{\THEYEAR{} \shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]{} le {\THEDAY}}

\begin{document}

  \fauvedate\today

\end{document}
```

I get the date like if I don’t use `\fauvedate`:

[image: 17 novembre 2015]

So, how can I have in the same time polyglossia and my special date style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not load both `babel` and `polyglossia`.

It's a bit unfortunate that, due to how `polyglossia` sets a definition for `\today`, you need to set the language before loading `datetime`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

\newdateformat{fauvedate}{\THEYEAR{} \shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]{} le {\THEDAY}}

\begin{document}

\fauvedate\today

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just ran into same problem. Loading babel after datetime destroys the date adjustment, including "\newdateformat".  Appears to me that anybody who uses datetime should be urged to always put \usepackage{babel} right before that.  Or polylossia.